# Capturing the oozie spark action output

Tags: shell, apache-spark, hadoop, oozie

I want to capture the console output of a spark job in Oozie. I know that the oozie spark action doesn't support `<capture-output>`. So, I wrapped my spark job in a shell action as the shell action supports `<capture-output>`.

I printed out a line in my spark program like below

```
println("result=this is a pen")
```

and tried to read it using `${wf:actionData("action-id")["Variable"]}`. But, I got a null value.

I am able to capture the output that I am echoing from the shell which is calling the spark job above but not the value that I am printing in my spark program. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you check in the YARN logs what is actually output by the shell & by its child process i.e. the Spark driver?

Comment: You can do one thing catch the application ID from the stack produced in the shell for the spark job and use that application ID to get the stdout like this yarn logs -applicationId application_1211221211212 >> YarnStdOut.txt